# How is this SSL question off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I [recently](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108634/comodo-ssl-analyzer-error-14) asked about using [Comodo's SSL Analyser](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/) which despite being a simple one, is still a web application to check SSL certificates. The [FAQ here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) AFAIK is about using web applications?

So, I just want to understand why my question is off topic.

Comment: I am not creating anything, asking about the error message I got there. I only wish I was a Comodo employee and getting money for that tool. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Questions about the web interfaces to particular online tools are really only on-topic here to the extent that they are about *using* the web interface itself.  You are asking about the reasons behind a particular error message, which is not really our expertise here.

This is akin to asking:

> Is Google Spreadsheets internally using a heuristic to try and thwart divide-by-zero errors?

versus

> Which worksheet function to I use to get my stock data into a Google spreadsheet?

The former is almost exclusively outside of our expertise on the site.  You're much better off asking that question on a site that specializes in the mechanics of programming web applications, where you'll get an answer that delves into the nitty-gritty of the underlying code and theory.  Not to say that our users couldn't possibly have this type of knowledge (I'm sure some do), but on-average, you're going to find folks here that know the mechanics of the everyday use of Google products, Facebook, etc., inside and out.

In terms of the close reason, we tend to use this for anything that's related to the programming, hosting, hands-on type aspects of web applications that are in some stage of development.  It's possible that this type of outcome for your troubleshooting is not your intention, but it allows for classification of the question without resorting to a custom close reason.

I'm fine with leaving your question here for the time being, but, rather than debating whether it's on-topic, I'd rather we/I/you found another SE site that will lend you their particular brand of expertise and help you get an answer.

Comment: @pnuts The question was migrated to Webmasters where it got two upvotes and an answer from the maintainer of the program.  I think that's proof enough that the question was definitely *not* in the right place.

Comment: @pnuts I'm really not honestly sure I'm getting what you are trying to say.  You're kind of talking in circles here.

Comment: @pnuts I don't think this user was claiming any sort of mistreatment.  Not everyone who stops by has to become a devotee.  I'm happy that this person's question was answered and very well received on the other site, but that's something I knew going into this, it wasn't just a lucky guess.  I'd love to retain more users, but even in an ideal world, some people just want their questions answered and that's it.