# Troubleshooting questions are currently off-topic in this community; should we keep it that way?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

A recent question that was migrated from this community to Super User caused a bit of confusion on Super User.  The reason is because, as our moderator Rubén politely explained, *"Troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications [Stack Exchange]"*.  Rubén also provided other reasons why that particular question was migrated.

I am wondering if the community feels that this is still a good policy for our community, or if we should consider modifying it.

Note that I don't have a strong position in either direction, so this is truly a question, and not a push in a particular direction.  I'm looking forward to a healthy discussion.

Comment: Thanks for opening this conversation. Here are some related posts [Troubleshooting guidance](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/88163) from 2015, [How is this SSL question off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4245/88163) from 2017

Comment: @Rubén You're welcome. I saw you getting stuck in a tough position over there, and thought that perhaps a policy change here could help.  Of course, we don't want to change a policy here unless it makes good sense, so I think an open discussion makes sense to see what everybody thinks.